# Is using the Internet OK?

Tags: halacha, internet, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

What Poskim rule that the Internet is totally ok to use (without a filter)? What Poskim rule that's it's never ok to use? What Poskim say that you can use it, but with a filter?

Comment: What prohibition do you think there could be? It's just electricity and computers talking. Aside from Shabbat, I don't know what the issue is. Please [edit] your post to clarify. It seems kind of unmotivated to me.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35110/759

Comment: @Double Aa it's not a dupe. That question is asking if there is a requirement. I'm asking WHO says there is a requirement.

Comment: You then chose a poor title for your question. Also it still might be a dupe http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3507/759.

Comment: No poskim will give a definitive ruling on using Internet per se. They give an eitzah tovah in the garb of a psak.