# Why create lust?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, sexuality

Why did G-d create lust (i.e. boys and girls)?

Comment: somewhat related? not much on the "why" though- http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/how-can-i-curb-my-sexual-desire

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Sanhedrin tried undoing it](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=69b&format=text) (Yoma 69b). It didn't work:

> אמרו הואיל ועת רצון הוא נבעי רחמי איצרא דעבירה בעו רחמי ואמסר בידייהו
>   אמר להו חזו דאי קטליתו ליה לההוא כליא עלמא חבשוהו תלתא יומי ובעו ביעתא
>   בת יומא בכל ארץ ישראל ולא אשתכח אמרי היכי נעביד נקטליה כליא עלמא ניבעי
>   רחמי אפלגא פלגא ברקיעא לא יהבי כחלינהו לעיניה ושבקוהו ואהני דלא מיגרי
>   ביה לאיניש בקריבתה
>
> After killing the Yetzer Hara for idolatry they tried killing the one
>   for lust. The Yetzer Hara told them that they'll destroy the world by
>   killing it so they held it in jail for three days. After three days
>   they saw that there were no eggs (since all lost their attraction).
>
> Since they couldn't kill it fully, and they couldn't kill only the bad
>   side (attraction to women who aren't wives), they "blinded" the
>   Yetzer, so people aren't attracted to family.

( *my own, free translation* )

Comment: That's the same gemara as my answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA it is, but I think adding the quote is helpful.

Answer (score 14):

God created within all animals an urge to procreate. Without it, we would just end. ([Sanhedrin 64a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=64&format=pdf))