# physical drive to look at ראיות אסורות

Tags: shemirat-eynayim

What gives a person the physical drive to look at *forbidden* images, and for that matter men's drive to look at women?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48459/759

Comment: Do you mean on a biological level?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: I think that the fundamental drive of human being is to know. The hidden parts of the body are as unknown, despite that everybody knows them. The irresistible curiosity is a deviant instinct of knowledge, which is exacerbated when a man is not involved fully in search of truth.

Comment: how do you know it is a physical drive?

Comment: @kouty i definitely agree with you on this. Which is why it's unfortunate that i find women in skirts much more appealing than women in jeans.

Comment: @Aaron the topic is clear and each detail can be explained easily. I want only to explain how the drive is functioning. in Tora too Yedia is used concerning relationship with woman. A man is not a standard animal, because human thinking is very different from animals thinking

Answer (score 1):

the same one as the drive for all sins - the ruach hatuma which gives a certain pleasure as the vilna gaon writes:

> "in everything a person does, a ruach (spirit) is sent down from
>   heaven , and helps him to repeat more things like these. And this
>   spirit does not rest and quiet until the person repeats more things
>   like this. The person then finds pleasure in doing these things,
>   whether they are good (mitzvas) or evil (sins). And this is what is
>   meant by 'sin brings sin and mitzva brings mitzva (pirkei avos 4:2)'"
>   And the greater the sin, the greater the spirit, and the greater the
>   lust to do more evil. And likewise for a great mitzva, a spirit from a
>   very holy place comes down and the person lusts immensely for another
>   mitzva. And because of this, he finds enormous pleasure in doing
>   mitzvos. As is known, the greatest of all mitzvos is learning Torah,
>   and the opposite is idle chatter and frivolity (letzanus) which is the
>   opposite of Torah. Therefore, there is greater pleasure in idle
>   chatter and frivolity than in all other sins, even though there is no
>   physical benefit, because the ruach hatuma (evil spirit) is
>   exceedingly great....but really, the pleasure in the holy spirit is
>   greater than the evil spirit (sin) because it is a true pleasure" -
>   commentary on Mishlei/Proverbs 1:23

looking at women *in order to derive pleasure* is a powerful sin as the talmud teaches (berachot 61a):

> " 'from hand to hand he shall not escape from evil' (Mishlei 11:21),
>   [this teaches] whoever counts out money from his hand to the hand of a
>   woman so as to have an excuse for gazing at her, even if he possesses
>   Torah and good deeds like Moses our teacher, shall not escape the
>   punishment of Gehinom"