# Mitzvah and connection. How does that work?

Tags: mitzvah, reward-punishment

If you do good deeds, are you then connected to good?
Do you draw blessing into your life?

How does Mitzvah connection to good work?

Comment: You might want to see the other questions tagged [tag:reward-punishment], and see if your question is covered there. If not, can you clarify quite what you mean by "conneciton", and what assumptions you are making about blessings?

Comment: Pirkei Avot says that the reward of a mitzvah is another mitzvah. Is this what you mean by "connection"?

Comment: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75830/1857

Answer (score 0):

Reb nachman explains it in l'kutei moharan 2, 59. That there is a so called 'something' that ties one mitzveh to the other one, and this stage of connection is also preciouse to g-d.

See here:

יֵשׁ זָרִיז וְנִשְׂכָּר, זָרִיז וְנִפְסָד (ע' פסחים נ:). כִּי דַע, כִּי מִצְוָה גּוֹרֶרֶת מִצְוָה (אבות פ"ד), נִמְצָא שֶׁהַמִּצְוָה גּוֹרֶרֶת אֶת חֲבֶרְתָּהּ. וּבְוַדַּאי יֵשׁ אֵיזֶה בְּחִינָה בֵּין הַמִּצְווֹת, מַה שֶּׁהוּא בֵּין מִצְוָה לְמִצְוָה, שֶׁהוּא מְקַשֵּׁר מִצְוָה אַחַת לַחֲבֶרְתָּהּ, אֲשֶׁר עַל־יְדֵי־ זֶה הַמִּצְווֹת נִגְרָרִים אַחַת אַחַר חֲבֶרְתָּהּ. וּבֶאֱמֶת זֹאת הַבְּחִינָה בְּעַצְמָהּ, הַיְנוּ מַה שֶּׁהוּא בֵּין הַמִּצְווֹת כַּנַּ"ל, זֹאת הַבְּחִינָה הִיא גַם־כֵּן יְקָרָה מְאֹד. וְעַל־כֵּן מִי שֶׁהוּא צַדִּיק מִנְּעוּרָיו וְהוֹלֵךְ בְּדֶרֶךְ הַיָּשָׁר מִיָּמָיו, מִדַּרְגָּא לְדַרְגָּא, כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב בְּאַבְרָהָם (בראשית כ"ד): וְאַבְרָהָם זָקֵן בָּא בַּיָּמִים – שֶׁאַבְרָהָם בָּא לַדַּרְגָּא שֶׁלּוֹ עַל־יְדֵי הַיָּמִים, כַּמּוּבָא בַּזֹּהַר (חיי שרה דף קכט.), כִּי בֶּן שָׁלֹשׁ שָׁנִים הִכִּיר אֶת בּוֹרְאוֹ (נדרים לב), וְהָיָה הוֹלֵךְ תָּמִיד מִדַּרְגָּא לְדַרְגָּא. וּמִי שֶׁהוּא בִּבְחִינָה זוֹ, הוּא מַפְסִיד עַל־יְדֵי הַזְּרִיזוּת. כִּי כְּשֶׁהוּא זָרִיז גָּדוֹל וְרָץ בִּזְרִיזוּת מִמִּצְוָה לְמִצְוָה, אֲזַי הוּא מַפְסִיד עַל־יְדֵי־זֶה אֶת בְּחִינַת הַקְּדֻשָּׁה, מַה שֶּׁהוּא בֵּין מִצְוָה לְמִצְוָה כַּנַּ"ל. כִּי עַל־יְדֵי זֶה הַזְּרִיזוּת הוּא עוֹבֵר וּמְדַלֵּג עַל הַבְּחִינָה הַזֹּאת, כִּי הַמִּצְוָה בְּעַצְמָהּ הוֹלֶכֶת אֵלָיו, כִּי הִיא נִמְשֶׁכֶת וְנִגְרֶרֶת אֵלָיו עַל־יְדֵי הַמִּצְוָה רִאשׁוֹנָה, שֶׁגּוֹרֶרֶת אֶת הַשְּׁנִיָּה כַּנַּ"ל. וּכְשֶׁגַּם הוּא רָץ בִּזְרִיזוּת אֶל הַמִּצְוָה, אֲזַי יוּכַל לְדַלֵּג וְלַעֲבֹר אֶת הַבְּחִינָה הַנַּ"ל, דְּהַיְנוּ מַה שֶׁהוּא בֵּין הַמִּצְווֹת כַּנַּ"ל, וְעַל־כֵּן הוּא זָרִיז וְנִפְסָד. אֲבָל כְּשֶׁשּׁוֹהֶה קְצָת, יוּכַל בְּתוֹךְ כָּךְ לְהַשִּׂיג גַּם הַבְּחִינָה שֶׁבֵּין הַמִּצְווֹת כַּנַּ"ל. וְכָל זֶה – לְמִי שֶׁהוֹלֵךְ בְּדַרְכֵי ה' כַּסֵּדֶר מִנְּעוּרָיו. אֲבָל מִי שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לַעֲשׂוֹת תְּשׁוּבָה, הוּא צָרִיךְ דַּוְקָא לִהְיוֹת זָרִיז גָּדוֹל מְאֹד מְאֹד, לְמַהֵר וְלָרוּץ מְאֹד, לְהִמָּלֵט עַל נַפְשׁוֹ, וְאָסוּר לוֹ לִשְׁהוֹת כְּלָל לַעֲמֹד וּלְהִתְיַשֵּׁב, כִּי בַּעַל־תְּשׁוּבָה אֵינוֹ הוֹלֵךְ מִדַּרְגָּא לְדַרְגָּא כְּלָל, וְאֵין בֵּינוֹ וּבֵין הַקְּדֻשָּׁה שׁוּם בְּחִינָה הַנַּ"ל, כִּי הוּא צָרִיךְ לְהַתְחִיל מֵחָדָשׁ, וְהוּא צָרִיךְ לָרוּץ וּלְדַלֵּג אֶל הַקְּדֻשָּׁה, כַּמּוּבָא, שֶׁהַבַּעַל־תְּשׁוּבָה צָרִיךְ לְדַלֵּג עַל מַה שֶּׁצָּרִיךְ לְדַלֵּג, וְלִקְפֹּץ אֶל הַקְּדֻשָּׁה בִּזְרִיזוּת גָּדוֹל. וְאִישׁ כָּזֶה הוּא זָרִיז וְנִשְׂכָּר כַּנַּ"ל: וּבְחִינָה שֶׁבֵּין הַמִּצְווֹת כַּנַּ"ל הוּא כְּגוֹן: וַיְדַבֵּר ה' אֶל מֹשֶׁה לֵּאמֹר וְעָשִׂיתָ. וּבְוַדַּאי יֵשׁ עֲבוֹדָה גַּם בְּאֵלּוּ הַדִּבּוּרִים, שֶׁהֵם קֹדֶם הַמִּצְוָה. כִּי עִקָּר הַמִּצְוָה בְּעַצְמָהּ נֶאֱמַר בַּתּוֹרָה אַחַר־כָּךְ, אַחַר תֵּבַת וְעָשִׂיתָ, אֲבָל בֶּאֱמֶת בְּוַדַּאי גַּם בַּפְּסוּקִים הַנַּ"ל שֶׁבֵּין מִצְוָה לְמִצְוָה, יֵשׁ בָּהֶם עֲבוֹדָה. וְזֶהוּ בְּחִינָה הַנַּ"ל מַה שֶּׁבֵּין מִצְוָה לְמִצְוָה. וְעוֹד יֵשׁ בָּזֶה, וְעַיֵּן בְּמָקוֹם אַחֵר (בלקו"א סי' כב) מֵעִנְיָן זֶה, שֶׁבֶּאֱמֶת יֵשׁ עֲבוֹדָה גַּם בַּפָּסוּק וַיְדַבֵּר וְכוּ':

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, "good" is synonymous with true "existence". Hence Hashem who has true and independent existence, is "good". By doing mitzvos, you cause yourself to "exist more", this is "tov". By doing aveiros, you cause yourself to exist less, this is "ra".

If you cleave to Hashem's, you bring blessing into your life, because blessing is success that is predicated on the true good of Hashem's existence.