# Mitzvot that "are practiced" vs Chayav and Patur

Tags: halacha-theory, mishna, maseches-kiddushin

The Mishnah Kiddushin (1:8-9) and the following Gemmorah (35-36) use the word "מצוות נוהגות" instead of the accepted "אנשים חייבים" or "נשים פטורות":

> "הַסְּמִיכוֹת,..., וְהַקַּבָּלוֹת, נוֹהֲגִין בַּאֲנָשִׁים וְלֹא בְנָשִׁים, ...:
>
> The leanings, ... and the collections of blood **are practiced** by men, but not by women...
>
> כָּל מִצְוָה שֶׁהִיא תְלוּיָה בָאָרֶץ אֵינָהּ נוֹהֶגֶת אֶלָּא בָאָרֶץ. וְשֶׁאֵינָהּ תְּלוּיָה בָאָרֶץ נוֹהֶגֶת בֵּין בָּאָרֶץ בֵּין בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ...:
>
> Any commandment which is dependent on the Land [of Israel] is only practiced in the Land. etc

What are the source and the explanation for such language?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93987/16706

Comment: @Shmuel What do you mean? We are talking real Mitzvos here, not traditions

Comment: They’re both questioning and delving into the usage of the word נוהג while I personally think it’s just semantics -